# php 5.3 fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource error

Tags: php, wampserver

I am using wamp server. I try to write into the file but it is giving such error: "Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given ". How can I solve it?

```
$file = 'file.txt';  
if (($fd = fopen($file, "a") !== false)) { 
  fwrite($fd, 'message to be written' . "\n");   
  fclose($fd); 
}
```

Comment: As per PHP documentation *For portability, it is strongly recommended that you always use the 'b' flag when opening files with fopen()* try to do `$fb = fopen($file, 'ab')`

Comment: You placed the parentheses wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Move parentheses:

```
if (($fd = fopen($file, "a")) !== false) { 
  fwrite($fd, 'message to be written' . "\n");   
  fclose($fd); 
}
```

Your code assigned the result of `(fopen($file, "a") !== false)` (i.e. a boolean value) to `$fd`.

Answer (score 3):

Do one thing at a time, because there is no rush and enough space:

```
$file = 'file.txt';
$fd = fopen($file, "a");
if ($fd) { 
    fwrite($fd, 'message to be written' . "\n");   
    fclose($fd); 
}
```

Especially make the code more easy in case you run into an error message.

Also know your language: A resource in PHP evaluates true, always.

And know your brain: A double negation is complicated, always.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `if` condition. PHP comparison binds more tightly than assignment, so the `fopen !== false` is first evaluating to `true`, and then the `true` is being written into `$fd`. You can use brackets to group `$fd = fopen($file, 'a')` together, or you can take that part out of the condition and write `if ($fd !== false)` for your condition instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `!== false` outside the ")"

Like this:

```
$file = 'file.txt';  
if (($fd = fopen($file, "a")) !== false) { 
  fwrite($fd, 'message to be written' . "\n");   
  fclose($fd); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

operator precedence is causing your problem. `!==` binds tighter than `=`, so your code is actually:

```
if ($fd = (fopen(...) !== false)) {
          ^--------------------^--
```

and you're assigning the boolean result of the `!==` comparison to $fd.

Either change the bracketing, or switch to the `or` operator,w hich has a lower binding precedence:

```
if (($fd = fopen(...)) !== false) {
    ^----------------^
```

or

```
$fd = fopen(...) or die('unable to open file');
```

Comment: or $fd=fopen(..);  if($fd) {...}

Comment: Please don't `die` ... (although a cynic could argue that if you're writing in php, you don't care about proper exception handling anyways)